# Как сделать прокрутку до верха страницы, чтобы контент новой вкладки читался с начала?

Tags: jquery, вкладки

Реализованы стандартные вкладки на сайте. 
При прокрутке страницы в мобильной версии они прилипают к верхнему краю и всегда доступны. Проблема в том, что при переключении на новую вкладку содержимое вкладки начинается не с начала, а того момента где просматривалась предыдущая вкладка. Как сделать прокрутку до верха страницы, чтобы контент новой вкладки читался с начала?

```
    function stickMenu() {
  var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var sectionStarts = $('#sectionStarts').offset().top;
  var sectionEnds = $('#sectionEnds').offset().top;

  if (windowTop > sectionEnds) {
    $('ul.nav.nav-tabs').removeClass('fixed');
  } else if (windowTop > sectionStarts) {
    $('ul.nav.nav-tabs').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('ul.nav.nav-tabs').removeClass('fixed');

  }



}

$(window).scroll(function() {
  stickMenu();
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте при рендере новой вкладки использовать window.scrollTo https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: Подскажите, как именно это сделать? Я новичок в этом.Мой код выше.